# How to pass custom attributes onClick in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to pass custom attribute `task` to function. following is the code but it is giving undefined

```
function handleChange(e)
{
   console.log(e.target.task)
}


const listTask = props.tasks.map((task)=>
{
   return(
      <option key={task._id} task={task}>{task.title}</option>
   )
})

return(

<select onChange={handleChange}>
       {listTask}
</select>
)
```

in `handleChange` method, I want to access `task` attribute is there any way?

Comment: I think you may want to use `e.target.getAttribute('task')` instead of `e.target.task`

Comment: Add `value={task._id}` to your options. Now use `props.tasks.find(task => task._id === e.target.value)` to find the task in the list based on the id. https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-violet-lps4n?file=/src/App.js (this is an xy problem, you do *not* want to pass a custom attribute to an option, all you want to do is find out which option was selected)

Comment: Every single answer here is wrong, I'm afraid, in case it's not clear.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```js
function handleChange(e, task) {
  console.log(task)
}


<select onChange={e => handleChange(e, task)}>
  <option key={task._id} task={task}>
    {task.title}
  </option>
</select>
```

---

Reference: [Passing Arguments to Event Handlers](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#passing-arguments-to-event-handlers)

Comment: This only works inside the loop where `task` is actually defined.